# One relationship with multiple models [interesting rails relations concept]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, model, relationship

I have this app where the model `User` can have multiple "channels". The channels part of the app has to be easily extendable each with **its own model**.

I started creating a `Channel` model with a `belongs_to` `User` relationship with the reverse of `User` `has_many` `Channel`.

I was thinking about having an API similar to this:

```
user = User.create(name: 'John')

user.channels.create(name: 'google', account_id: '1234') # should create a GoogleChannel::Google Model
user.channels.create(name: 'facebook', account_name: 'qwerty') # should create a FacebookChannel::Facebook Model
```

I am playing around with having a `Channel` model and each channel model having a dedicated model for each of the channels (google, facebook, etc.) with a `has_one` relationship to that model.

**Update:**

I'm using **mongoid** with rails

Comment: Seems like you're talking about STI.

Comment: or polymorphic ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works. It uses STI.

**First approach: Single Table Inheritance**

```
class User << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :channels
  delegate :google_channels, :facebook_channels, :twitter_channels, to: :channels
end

class Channel << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  self.inheritance_column = :brand

  scope :google_channels,   -> { where(brand: 'Google')   } 
  scope :facebook_channels, -> { where(brand: 'Facebook') } 
  scope :twitter_channels,  -> { where(brand: 'Twitter') }

  def self.brands
    %w(Google Facebook Twitter)
  end 
end

class GoogleChannel << Channel; end
class FacebookChannel << Channel; end
class TwitterChannel << Channel; end
```

I think you can:

```
current_user.channels << GoogleChannel.new(name: "First Google Channel") 
current_user.channels << Facebook.new(name: "Facebook") 
current_user.channels << Twitter.new(name: "Tweety")
current_user.channels << GoogleChannel.new(name: "Second Google Channel") 

googs = current_user.google_channels
all = current_user.channels
# etc.
```

All channels share the same table. If you need different attributes for each different brand, this would not be the best option.

**Second approach: Polymorphic models**

If you need different tables for each model (brand), you can use a polymorphic approach (not tested):

```
class User << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :channels
  has_many :google_channels, through: :channels, source: :branded_channel, source_type: 'GoogleChannel'
  has_many :facebook_channels, through: :channels, source: :branded_channel, source_type: 'FacebookChannel'
end

class Channel << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :branded_channel, polymorphic: true
end

#This channel has its own table, and can have more attributes than Channel
class GoogleChannel << ApplicationRecord
  has_one :channel, as: :branded_channel
end

#This channel has its own table, and can have more attributes than Channel
class FacebookChannel << ApplicationRecord
  has_one :channel, as: :branded_channel
end

goog = GoogleChannel.create(all_google_channel_params)
face = GoogleChannel.create(all_facebook_channel_params)
current_user.channels << Channel.new(branded_channel: goog)
current_user.channels << Channel.new(branded_channel: face)
```

Comment: hmm... quite interesting.

I'll give it a try today

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. A model for each brand (different tables) makes the most sense for the app I'm building.

I was hoping I would get an API like `user.channel.model.visit` and run the `visit` method on the channel model (eg: `GoogleChannel::Google`) without specifying the kind of channel that I want (`user.channels.google_channels`).

Comment: I posted a second approach using polymorphic models, but I'm not sure it works (with some changes it should)

Comment: Thank you Pablo, but I think that what I want is kind of "magic". Don't know if it's possible to do it my way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to create STI where `User` has many channels, so in Rails 5 you can try this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_channels
  has_many :channels, through: :user_channels
  has_many :facebook_channels, class_name: 'FacebookChannel', through: :user_channels
  has_many :google_channels, class_name: 'GoogleChannel', through: :user_channels
end

class UserChannel < ApplicationRecord
  # user_id
  # channel_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :channel
  belongs_to :facebook_channel, class_name: 'FacebookChannel', foreign_key: :channel_id, optional: true
  belongs_to :google_channel, class_name: 'GoogleChannel', foreign_key: :channel_id, optional: true
end

class Channel < ApplicationRecord
  # You need to have "type" column to be created for storing different chanels
  has_many :user_channels
  has_many :users, through: :user_channels
end

class FacebookChannel < Channel
  has_many :user_channels
  has_many :users, through: :user_channels
end

class GoogleChannel < Channel
  has_many :user_channels
  has_many :users, through: :user_channels
end
```

Now you can do `current_user.facebook_channels.create(name: "My Facebook Channel")` and get all `FacebookChannel` with `current_user.facebook_channels`

Basically it works like regular `has_many through` relationship with extra feature of STI - you store sub-model name in `type` column of `Channel` model.

**Update**

I'm sorry, I didn't know my suggestion is not working with MongoDB. Maybe you can simply create `channel_type` column in your `channels` table, have simple `channel belongs_to user` relationship and then do:

1. `current_user.channels.create(name: "My Channel Name", channel_type: "facebook")`
2. `current_user.channels.where(channel_type: "facebook")`

You could do simply `current_user.channels` which gives you all channels for user and then if you need you can do what ever you need with each record according to `channel_type` value.
You can even create some scopes in Channel model:

```
class Channel < ApplicationRecord
  scope :facebook_channels, -> { where(channel_type: "facebook") }
end
```

And then you can do your desired `current_user.channels.facebook_channels`

`channel_type` column could be string or integer if you do it with enums.

In addition if you create `visit` column (e.g. "boolean"), you can do `current_user.channels.where(visit: true)` or create `scope :visit_true, -> { where(visit: true) }` and do something like `current_user.channels.visit_true`

What do you say?

Comment: Well, it's more of multi table relationships. I was hoping to have the api more of `current_user.channel.model` and not knowing what kind of model that is. So I don't have to guess/find out if it's a google or a facebook channel.

Comment: BTW, I'm using mongoid, so no `has_many_through` relationships for me :|

Comment: @adrianthedev Please, see my Update above.

Comment: Yup @matiss. That's somewhat what I did. It's not the rails/AR/relationships way, but it'll do for me.

Now I have this bridge model `Channel` and each one has a different model for each channel (so I don't overload the `Channel` model). 
The thing that I regret not having is relationship queries. I can't do `current_user.channels.where(url: 'google.com')` without knowing what kind of channel it is unless I store the `url` (or any other attributes I might need for queries) attribute to the `Channel` model (which might overload it in the long term).

Thanks a lot for the answers!